# The way to imrove vimdiff similarity-searching mechanism

Tags: vimdiff

I'm trying to understand how vimdiff work.

Here I tried to diff two simple files. The 1st:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

foo

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz iii

bar
```

The 2nd:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

Here is result from diffmerge utility:

[image]

And here is result from vim:

[image]

Note that vim doesn't see the similarity between `abc...xyz` and `abc...xyz iii` lines and doesn't arrange them visually on one line.

Is there some settings to improve vimdiff in such cases?

Comment: Try the diffchar plugin. It might improve things.

Comment: I tried it, unfortunately does not work. It cannot find the best matching lines.